# Spring/Mockito - Testing a controller

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

This is the controller class i have written,

```
@RestController
public class TranslatorController {

    @Autowired
    TransResponse transResponse;

    @Autowired
    TransRequest transRequest;

    @Autowired
    TransWorker worker;

    @PostMapping(path = "/trans", consumes = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, produces = {
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<TransResponse> translate(@RequestBody TransRequest transRequest,
            Errors error, HttpServletRequest request) {

        logger.info("Starting translation::-->" + transRequest.getTerm());
        String trans = worker.trans(transRequest.getText());
        transResponse.setStatus("OK");
        transResponse.setTrans(trans);
        transResponse.setMessage("SUCCESS");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(transResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

This is the test class for this,

```
@WebMvcTest(TranslatorController.class)
@ComponentScan("com.demo.service")
public class TranslatorControllerTest {

    @Mock
    TransRequest transRequest;

    @Mock
    Errors error; 

    @Mock
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

    @Mock
    private TranslatorController controllerMock;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    TransWorker worker;

    @Mock
    ResponseEntity<TransResponse> respEntity;

    @Test
    public void testTranslate() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(worker.trans(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("cold");
        TransResponse response = new TransResponse();
        response.setTrans("cold");
        respEntity = new ResponseEntity<TransResponse>(response,
                HttpStatus.OK);
        Mockito.when(controllerMock.translate(transRequest, error, httpRequest)).thenReturn(respEntity);
        respEntity = controllerMock.translate(transRequest, error, httpRequest);
        assertEquals("cold", respEntity.getBody().getTrans());
    }
}
```

Its passing as success

But my question is am i doing the test correctly? If it is not correct. Please can you guide me where i am wrong.

Comment: What exactly do you think you're testing here? You've mocked everything out! Heck, half the mocks you've written never get called. You could comment out the implementation and still pass the tests, which is a pretty good sign you've done something wrong. You might want to look into TDD; it's important to make sure the test fails for a sensible reason when the implementation is wrong or not yet written.

Comment: Please can you provide a reference or example

Answer (score 4):

I think it's good to use `@WebMvcTest`! It's just that you shouldn't mock `TranslatorController` as `@WebMvcTest` will provide you with an instance.

The controller's dependencies need to be mock, which is achieved by annotating them with `@MockBean` (the mocked instances will be injected into the controller).

Then, instead of calling your Controller's method, use `MockMvc` to send a test *HTTP* request, which will be caught by your controller.

```
ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                       .post("/trans")
                       .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

                       //whatever JSON content expected as input
                       .content("{trans: \"something\"}")));

resultActions.andExpect(status().isOk());

//validates stuff..
resultActions.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
```

The whole test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(TranslatorController.class)
public class TranslatorControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    TransResponse transResponse;

    @MockBean
    private TransRequest transRequest;

    @MockBean
    TransWorker worker;

    @Test
    public void testTranslate() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(worker.trans(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("cold");

        ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                               .post("/trans")
                               .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

                               //whatever JSON content expected as input
                               .content("{trans: \"something\"}")));

        resultActions.andExpect(status().isOk()
                     .andExpect(content().string("{trans: \"cold\"}"));

        //validates stuff..
        resultActions.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
    }
}
```

This allows you to actually test the real behaviour of your controller when it receives the JSON payload. If you just call its method (which may also be valid tests), then you won't be able to tests invalid JSON scenarios or security checks (user in role....) for instance.

The documentation shows example: https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4:

> ```
> @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
> @WebMvcTest(UserVehicleController.class)
> public class UserVehicleControllerTests {
>
>     @Autowired
>     private MockMvc mvc;
>
>     @MockBean
>     private UserVehicleService userVehicleService;
>
>     @Test
>     public void getVehicleShouldReturnMakeAndModel() {
>         given(this.userVehicleService.getVehicleDetails("sboot"))
>             .willReturn(new VehicleDetails("Honda", "Civic"));
>
>         this.mvc.perform(get("/sboot/vehicle")
>             .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN))
>             .andExpect(status().isOk())
>             .andExpect(content().string("Honda Civic"));
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are testing what you want. It seems like you are trying to test your controller's `translate` method, but you mock your controller. You shouldn't mock what you are trying to test.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TranslatorControllerTest {

  @InjectMocks
  TranslatorController controller;   

  @Mock
  TransResponse transResponse;

  @Mock
  TransRequest transRequest;

  @Mock
  TransWorker worker;

  @Test
  public void testTranslate() throws Exception {
     Mockito.when(worker.trans(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("cold");

     TransResponse response = controller.translate(transRequest, null, new MockHttpServletRequest();
     Assert.assertEquals("cold", response.getBody().getTrans());
  }

}
```

Of course you will need to also test your `TransWorker` class, as this is essentially a call through.